# How to use Text file with clickonce and be able to update it when updating?

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a project and i want to use clickonce...

in the project directory, it has text files on it needed bt my applications.

1. How can i deliver my program with the text files to my end users via clickonce?
2. What if i change the text files, added, and removed, and modify some, how can clickonce help me to replace the old textfiles and main program in my end program.
3. A sample pseudocode, if possible.

Tnx

Ps: the text files are used by my program but its not part of the source code.

Comment: When you say "what if I change the text files" you mean change them centrally, with the intent of then deploying the changes to all clients, right? As opposed to changing the files locally (like a settings file that an individual client might modify).

Comment: exactly. Ill be changing text files like weekly, and i want those textfiles be downloaded to them, and delete all old textfiles which doesnt exist centrally.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can deliver with you programe a text file to your end user. You can [embed the file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) in your application and deliver it with ClickOnce.

Steps (from MSDN) are :

1. Right-click your project name, click
   Add, and then click Add New Item. In
   the New Item dialog box, select Text
   File from the menu, and name the
   file MyTextFile.txt. When the file
   opens in the integrated development
   environment (IDE), add some text,
   and then close the file.
2. Right-click either the text file,
   and then select Properties.

   In the Properties dialog box, locate
   the Build Action property. By
   default, this property is set to
   Content.
3. Click the property and change the Build Action property to Embedded Resource.

2) Everytime you will do a new version, ClickOnce will send back the new Text Resource

3)

```
StreamReader _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNameSpace.MyTextFile.txt"));
Console.WriteLine(_textStreamReader.ReadLine());
```

Comment: thnx but the question is, how can old textfiles(old release) be deleted in the update (they dont appear in central server when new version is released)?

Comment: It's embed so the old file will not be available after an Update. Just the newer will be there.

Comment: Tnx but i have an sample.exe file and its the one reading the text files. My program just simply launches and start the process sample.exe. can sample.exe embedded in clickonce deployment?

Comment: lets say sample.exe is embedded, how can it be launch in process and read the text files embedded also? Tnx

Comment: When you sample.exe is launch, it will go check if a new version is available. If it find a new version, the sample.exe will be changed with the new one. The "new one" will contain the new .txt file and will be able to read it...

Comment: you dont have to delete old text files if it is in the same folder as the `exe` because new version will be installed in a different folder

Comment: @daok hello.. sample.exe is together with the textfiles.. my main program (mainapp.exe) will embed sample.exe and textfiles,, is it possible to embed those 2 files? and also,, how can i access the exefile in the resources,, then start it? thx

Comment: i see.. Also i have 1 question, if my mainapp.exe is click by the user, how can i extract the sample.exe together with the text files (embedded resources)in a directory.

Comment: You can click up arrow to tell that you like the assistant I gave to you and you can accept answer too if the answer give the best information for your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on your ClickOnce project and choose properties, and then click application files. If your text file and exe file is has status "include" and "required" the files will be copyed to the local client every time you release a new version of your project.

Just make sure that your clickonce project settings let clients automatically check for updates every time the application starts. (Click the "Updates" button just beneath the application files button)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the files to your project. Set the build action to "content", and set "copy to output directory" to "copy always". Then when you publish, the files should be included with the assemblies. I assume you're letting the users access these programmatically?

When you want to change the files, just change them and publish a new version and make it a required update -- in the Updates dialog, set the minimum version to the same version you're releasing, and be sure you're checking for updates before the appliaction runs. It will create a new folder for the new version and put the text files you have in the project there, and not copy the old ones forward.